# Read value from XML within another XML: Mule

Tags: xpath, mule

I am making a SOAP webservice call and I get the below response. I want to read the value in internal XML, the value is 12345684 in 1234684 in the below XML.

I was able to get internal XML using `#[xpath3('//:processaResponse /return[2]')]`, store it in a flow variable and `#[xpath3('/AckReg/DataArea/PRegistration/PRDet/Person/IDSet/:ID[@schemeName="aid"]/text()')]`.
This works when I try an online parser, but it doesn't read the value in Mule.

Is there any way to extract 1234684 in `oa:ID` tag using one XPath.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ns3:TXID xmlns:ns3="http://a.d.r.test.com/"></ns3:TXID>
        <ns3:SESSIONID xmlns:ns3="http://a.d.r.test.com/"></ns3:SESSIONID>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns3:processaResponse xmlns:ns3="http://a.d.r.test.com/" xmlns:ns2="http://p.r.test.com/">
            <return>Hi</return>
            <return>
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <AckReg
     xmlns="http://www.test.com/e/1" languageCode="en-US" releaseID="normalizedString" systemEnvironmentCode="test" versionID="normalizedString"
     xmlns:oa="www.test.com/r/9"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test.com/a/1 ../test/test.xsd">
                    <Apa>
                        <oa:CreationDateTime>2018-04-05</oa:CreationDateTime>
                    </Apa>
                    <DataArea>
                        <Ack>
                            <OArea>
                                <o:Sender>
                                    <o:LID schemeAgencyName="testi" schemeName="Application ID">test</o:LID>

                                </o:Sender>
                            </OArea>
                            <OriginalActionVerb/>
                        </Ack>
                        <PRegistration>
                            <testids>
                                <IDSet schemeAgencyName="try">
                                    <oa:ID schemeName="abcid">1234684</oa:ID>
                                </IDSet>
                            </testids>
                            <PRDet>
                                <Person>
                                    <IDSet schemeAgencyName="try">
                                        <oa:ID schemeName="aid">1364561</oa:ID>
                                    </IDSet>
                                    <IDSet schemeAgencyName="enada">
                                        <oa:ID schemeName="Employee ID">adsad</oa:ID>
                                    </IDSet>
                                </Person>
                                <User>
                                    <oa:ID/>
                                </User>
                            </PRDet>
                        </PRegistration>
                    </DataArea>
                </AckReg>
            </return>
        </ns3:processaResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your expressions you were missing namespace prefixes or namespace wildcards `*:` on some nodes - so your expressions failed.

> Is there any way to extract 1234684 in oa:ID tag using one XPath.

Combining both of your partial expressions is possible with namespace wildcards:

```
//*:processaResponse/return[2]/*:AckReg/*:DataArea/*:PRegistration/*:testids/*:IDSet/*:ID[@schemeName='abcid']/text()
```

Or you can use an absolute path with namespace wildcards:

```
/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:processaResponse/return[2]/*:AckReg/*:DataArea/*:PRegistration/*:testids/*:IDSet/*:ID[@schemeName='abcid']/text()
```

**Output in both cases:**

> 1234684

Answer (score 0):

You can even use XmlSlurper class using groovy script to fetch that respective value.
root = new XmlSlurper( false, true).parseText(payload).declareNamespace('soapenv':"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")